# How to take a screenshot in console (without X)?

Tags: tty, screenshot

My netbook runs on Debian Linux without X.org. I sometimes need to make a screenshot of the output of scripts. I tried to use a framebuffer device for this purpose:

```
# cat /dev/fb0 > screenshot.raw
```

But the problem is that this `.raw` file is not a graphic format since it cannot even be opened with GIMP. How it's possible to convert it to `.png` file, for example?

Comment: [`raspi2png`](https://github.com/AndrewFromMelbourne/raspi2png) is the only tool that worked for me even to capture OpenGL renderings, using no X server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of the raw file you capture is going to depend on the bit depth and resolution.

There are a number of tools out there to do this.  Debian has the `fbcat` package.  You may need to `sudo apt-get install fbcat` to install it.

`fbcat` will grab the frame buffer in `ppm` format, so you can then use `ppmtojpeg` or similar to convert it to the format you want.

There's also a `fbgrab` wrapper which will save in PNG format.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen. fbcat utility working as need... fbgrab generated a png file but it's not viewable((

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `sudo setterm --dump` command to print the content of the current tty into a text file, the default output is `screen.dump` file. The `--file` option can be used to get a custom output file name: `sudo setterm --dump --file screen0.dump`.

[`man setterm`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/util-linux/setterm.1.en.html) :

> ```
> --dump [console_number]
> ```
>
> Writes  a  snapshot of the virtual console with the given number to the file specified with the `--file` option, overwriting its contents; the default is screen.dump.  Without an argument, it dumps the  current virtual console.  This overrides `--append`.